# black and white aerial ortophoto classification using texture with GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, classification, imagery

I have a b&w image i want to classify; the trouble is that mere spectral classification yields a lot of error,
I saw this in [wikigrass](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_classification)

> In case of panchromatic maps or limited amount of channels, it is
>   often recommended to generate synthetic channels through texture
>   analysis (r.texture)

And there's nothing more about it in that page;
How can I use the outcome from r.texture in a classification, together with the segments of i.segment or i.smap?

Comment: Just use it as an additional channel, together with R,G,B or the like. I.e., create an imagery group with i.group which contains also the texture and segments maps, then run the classification on it.

Comment: Which function should I use for classifying with the polygons from i.segment? I want to use an object based classification

Answer (score 3):

After researching a lot, I've found/developed this GEOBIA workflow for GRASS GIS in combination with R machine learning:

in GRASS:
calculate the texture with *r.texture*;
make the objects with *i.segment* and vectorize this output with *r.to.vect*,
then extract the raster's graylevel and texture features with *v.rast.stats* then choose some training objects and write a shapefile and a csv with *v.out.ogr*

in R, with RWeka:
divide your csv or dbf in training and test sets,
apply J48() and then predict(), bind the predicted vector to a column in your data.frame and save the dbf, then you'll have a fitted column